Using Identity API from scaffolded pages
We have front end web pages and a back-end API.
We want to add MS's Identity solution.
We added the UI using the scaffolding.
The pages come up nicely.
But to work, they need a connection to the database.
Our front end doesn't have access to the database.
Everything goes through the API web service.
Now, with the advent of .NET 8, we have the Identity API, which should be the solution to our problem.
We now have the API in our solution, as seen through Swagger.
The remaining mystery is how to connect the two.
The Identity github project comes with sample projects, but it doesn't look like any of them show how to use the API. I suspect they are just left over from the previous version before there was an API and have since been abandoned.
I thought that we could descend from the UserManager and hijack all the calls to turn it into a facade and delegate all the work to the API.  But that's turning out to be more complicated, with claims and such, than I anticipated and I'm starting to question our direction.
Alternately, there are projects where they override the UserStore, etc, to get the data from another source, which is exactly what we want.
Is that a better direction?
Has anyone tried that approach yet to get the data from the API?

Is your front end a SPA, or Blazor or ... ? The IdentityApiEndpoints added in .NET 8 provide a default implementation, if you require custom handling you'll be better off ignoring them and rolling your own.

The scaffolded pages and the API endpoints are fine for us. We just need to be able to get to the endpoints from the pages they created for us.

From my understanding you just want use the scaffold identitypages with the build-in identity api. Do you have problem fetching the apis from front end?  And is there any examples about everride userStore?

@QiangFu Yes. The "problem" is that the front end doesn't have access to the database. The API does. So we want to use the API from the front end. There are examples of overriding the Store, and it looks like that is the way to go. But none that use the API. Interestingly, the methods in IUserStore don't match up with the methods exposed by the API, so we'll have to sort that out.

@Peppermintology The scaffolded pages are Razor.
